# Are these hypothese valid for a hypothesis test?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

In my textbook there is a question with the following hypotheses.
$H$<sub>0</sub> $: \mu + 5 = 175$, with $H$<sub>1</sub>: $\mu + 5 > 175$, now my question is, are these valid hypotheses and if so, are they identical to saying the following:
$H$<sub>0</sub> $: \mu = 170$ and $H$<sub>1</sub> $: \mu 
  > 170$, I am merely confused about this only because every other hypothesis test I've done is of the form $H$<sub>0</sub> $: \mu = k$, with one of the following, $H$<sub>1</sub> $: \mu > k $ , $H$<sub>1</sub> $: \mu < k $ or $H$<sub>1</sub> $: \mu  ≠k $ .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is exactly the same (with my edit, you had put 175 when I think you meant 170). You can subtract 5 from both sides.

Comment: Alright but when I do the question, it doesn't work. Could I attach the question here for you to help me with? I don't want my post to get deleted though